# in xslt match decimal with in text and write after it

Tags: html, xslt, foreach, xslt-1.0, contains

I have a problem. I think it is simple but I havent found it.
like below code I want to find and match multiplier factor value like "0.05" with "005" in the note value dynamically and take text "AAA" after "_ 005 _"(without spaces) and write it and others too.

I tried to use together both format number and concatenate to "concat(format-number(***))" but failed because of newby about this.

```
<cbc:Note>40.00 BT</cbc:Note>
        <cbc:Note>17_                       2005.00</cbc:Note>
        <cbc:Note>11_005_AAA</cbc:Note>
        <cbc:Note>11_002_BBB</cbc:Note>
        <cbc:Note>11_003_CCC</cbc:Note>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="CS">1.000</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="TRY">200.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:AllowanceCharge>
            <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
            <cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.03</cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>
            <cbc:Amount currencyID="TRY">6.00</cbc:Amount>
            <cbc:BaseAmount currencyID="TRY">200.00</cbc:BaseAmount>
        </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:AllowanceCharge>
            <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
            <cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.05</cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>
            <cbc:Amount currencyID="TRY">10.00</cbc:Amount>
            <cbc:BaseAmount currencyID="TRY">200.00</cbc:BaseAmount>
        </cac:AllowanceCharge>
```

current xslt block

```
<xsl:for-each select="./cac:AllowanceCharge/cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric">
                    <br/>
                    <xsl:text> %</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(. * 100, '###.##0,00', 'european')"/>,
            </xsl:for-each>
```

I appreciate if you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **very** difficult to understand your question.

The following **minimal** example is mostly based on a guess. It formats the `MultiplierFactorNumeric` value as a 3-digit whole number and uses it as a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to retrieve the corresponding `Note` value:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <Note>40.00 BT</Note>
    <Note>17_                       2005.00</Note>
    <Note>11_005_AAA</Note>
    <Note>11_002_BBB</Note>
    <Note>11_003_CCC</Note>
    <AllowanceCharge>
        <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.03</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
    </AllowanceCharge>
    <AllowanceCharge>
        <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.05</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
    </AllowanceCharge>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="note" match="Note" use="substring-before(substring-after(., '_'), '_')" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="AllowanceCharge">
            <item>
                <factor>
                    <xsl:value-of select="MultiplierFactorNumeric"/>
                </factor>
                <value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(key('note', format-number(100*MultiplierFactorNumeric, '000')), '_'), '_')"/>
                </value>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <item>
    <factor>0.03</factor>
    <value>CCC</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <factor>0.05</factor>
    <value>AAA</value>
  </item>
</result>
```

Comment: That was brilliant detective work, @michael.hor257k. It would never have occurred to me that's what the question was asking.

Comment: thanks @michael.hor257k. but I need a help too about it. if more than 1 root and of course note there are giving error like this: " Fatal Error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring-after() ("11_003_AAA", "21_003_AAA", ...) A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring-after() ("11_003_AAA", "21_003_AAA", ...)"

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with a problem I cannot reproduce. I suggest you post a new question and show a [mcve] - like the one included in my answer.